# How to call a method in its onSubmit event?

Tags: javascript

I try to implement file uploader script from [this Github project](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader) and I need to set some additional params from the form before submitting the upload.

According to the documentation it's being set like that:

```
uploader.setParams({
   anotherParam: 'value' 
});
```

How can I set these parameters in the onSubmit event? Something like:

```
var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
  onSubmit: function() {
    // <- I want to set the params here
  }
});
```

I tried `self.setParams()` and `this.setParams()` but no luck. I'm not that advanced in javascript so I would be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same code you posted. "uploader" will exist when onSubmit is called

```
var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
    onSubmit: function() {
        uploader.setParams({
            anotherParam: 'value' 
        });
    }
});
```